# como leer de csv valores exclusivos de una columna

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo un csv con algunos campos pero solo necesito leer la tercera columna que se llama email, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 fs.readFile('userDiferentPrice.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    console.log(dataArray);
  });
```

me lee el csv, pero me trae todos los campos separados por coma, solo necesito la tercera columna que posee un encabezado que se llama email y que no esten vacios, habra alguna forma? disculpen estoy comenzando con node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `dataArray` tienes ahora arreglos que contienen cada una de las filas del `.csv` luego lo que tienes que hacer es un split de cada fila y acceder al tercer dato.

Con eso tu código quedaría así:

```
fs.readFile("userDiferentPrice.csv", "utf8", function (err, data) {
  var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);

  lines.forEach(line => {
    const email = line.split(',')[2]; // Revisamos la tercera posición de cada linea

    if (email.length === 0) {
      console.log('El email está vacío');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Gracias Daniel, es perfecto,